# New custom nev not working

Tags: templates, buddypress

I am suffreing from an issue from last few days. I have to create a custon nev calls ribbons, that will have some custom functionlity but at the starting steps I am not able to create the nev pages. From lots of R &D I have cerate a code for ribbons custon nev

```
function custom_setup_nav() {
    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
        'name' => __( 'Rebons', 'buddypress' ),
        'slug' => 'rebons',
        'position' => 30,
        'show_for_displayed_user' => true,
        'default_subnav_slug' => 'rebons',
        'item_css_id' => 'rebons'
    ) );

    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
        'name' => __( 'Rebons', 'buddypress' ),
        'slug' => 'rebons',
        'screen_function' => 'rebons_page',
        'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->slug . '/',
        'parent_slug' => $bp->slug,
        'position' => 10,
        'item_css_id' => 'rebons'
    ) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'custom_setup_nav' );

function rebons_page() {

    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'rebons_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/rebons' ) );

}


function rebons_content(){

    echo 'Put your content here!';

}
```

From this code I got a option in nev ribbions but when i click on it i shows a 404 not found `error_get_last`. I have created a file ribbons.php according to profile.php file and aslo created a ribbons folder by copying profile folder and do some changes in files.

But I still getting 404 error. Is I have to registor nev by any functionlity

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you've shown, the main problem is this:

```
bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/rebons' ) );
```

Should be this:

```
bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
```

The way you are adding the nav tabs may also be a problem.
[Here is a gist that might help](https://gist.github.com/shanebp/5d3d2f298727a0a036e5).

> I have created a file ribbons.php according to profile.php file and
>   aslo created a ribbons folder by copying profile folder and do some
>   changes in files.

You shouldn't need to do that. And if you did, it would require creating a custom BP component and adding to the BP template stack - a much more complicated process.